# HTML to PDF for Azure app_service or functions

Tags: pdf-generation

I'm looking for the best component to generate HTML to PDF either through an app_service or a function hosted in Azure. We have a large volume of PDFs to generate, on average 2000 per days but this number increases month on month. Therefore we are looking for the best combination based on performance and capability to design our PDFs that provides an acceptable look and feel. Finally each file size is always between 30 and 80 kB

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion [Essential PDF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf/html-to-pdf) supports converting HTML to PDF and can be deployed to [Azure](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7546/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-in-azure-website)

```
        //Initialize HTML to PDF converter 
        HtmlToPdfConverter htmlConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter(HtmlRenderingEngine.WebKit);
        WebKitConverterSettings webKitSettings = new WebKitConverterSettings();


        //Assign WebKit settings to the converter
        htmlConverter.ConverterSettings = webKitSettings;

        //Convert url to pdf
        PdfDocument document = htmlConverter.Convert(url);  

        //Save the document.
        document.Save("Sample.pdf");
        document.Close();
```

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the community license program if you qualify (less than 1 million US Dollars in revenue). The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.